# Как растянуть в ширину text (Python tkinter)

Tags: python, gui, tkinter, текст

У меня есть вот такой текст

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но проблема в том что он не растягиваеться в ширину по всему окну *Tkinter* и выглядит это вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также я пробовал решить проблему через метод `width` и `fill`, но ничего из этого не сработало.

Создавал текст, вот так:

`tk.Label(f,width=80,height=2,bg='purple',text=f"{itog}").pack()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `.pack(fill=tk.X)`. Тогда элемент заполнит всё пространство по горизонтали и будет растягиваться при изменении размеров родительского виджета. Если он этого не делает, то смотрите параметры размещения этого родительского виджета (`f` в вашем случае) и какие параметры заполнения у него. И так далее по иерархии.
Пример, на котором работает как вам требуется.

```
import tkinter as tk

itog = "Some very very long is here."
root = tk.Tk()
f = tk.Frame(root)
f.pack(fill=tk.X)
tk.Label(f,width=80,height=2,bg='purple',text=f"{itog}").pack(fill=tk.X)
root.mainloop()
```

Ещё у `pack()` есть полезный параметр `expand=True/False`. Обычно комбинацией этих опций (*expand* и *fill*) можно добиться требуемого поведения виджета. Но опять же, напоминаю, что поведение надо выстраивать по всей иерархии. Если, к примеру, родительскому контейнеру не задали разрешение менять ширину, то все дочерние  элементы будут упираться в него.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x100")

label = tk.Label(root, height=2, bg='purple', text="Hello World")
label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)                       # weight=1

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]